# Term for type information from C Source Code

Tags: c, naming, documentation

I'm writing a code that extracts information about functions (prototype) and types (`enum`, `struct`, `typedef`) from a C source file.

This is to augment the type information about a particular function or type in my documentation.

Basically, I don't want to manually specify type information because that information can already be found in the source code itself.

Now I'm a bit indecisive about how to name that "extracted" information.

I thought about calling it `c meta data` or `c symbols` although I'm not sure what constitutes a `symbol` in C: I'm not sure if a struct type is a symbol, for example.

`c types` would also be "wrong" because functions are not types.

Is there a canonical term that both covers function prototypes AND type information?

Comment: "Types" is actually a reasonable choice, even if functions are involved. The signature of a function object is its type, and in C you can have function pointers whose type describes their signature.

Comment: I believe the standard calls these "declarations". A mere type is not a symbol, although a function is a symbol.

Comment: Consider: Declared Types. Would exclude primitives and predefined types.

Comment: This is also the information typically found in C-style "header" files, though still text, of course.

Comment: Another tip: there are various "language server" tools for e.g. emacs and VSCode which can already do this in a standard way, which may save you time

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs! I think I'm going with "declarations". I prepared a comment talking about the (in my opinion unjustified) closing of this question - since it has been re-opened with a minor edit I can safely discard that criticism. @pjc50 If you make your comment an answer I'll happily accept it!

Comment: @pjc50 I'm aware of "language servers" and I'm using `clangd` with Sublime Text - it's really helpful. I'm not entirely sure where you were going with this comment though. My question is unrelated to that (I think?). I'm using `clang` with `-ast-dump=json` to get the types and functions from the C source code, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Why not name it "declarations" or "declared types"?

Every declared function also has a declared type.

Answer (score -1):

An "identifier" is a generic word which can refer to keywords, types, variable names, function names, macros... They are sequences of letters, digits and underscores.

Additionally, you could use something like "c documentation" (more suitable as a title) or "c elements" (very generic, obviously).

Please remember that a "symbol" is usually only one character (either single byte, or multi-byte).

---

Note: you might want to have a look at the [**Doxygen**](https://www.doxygen.nl/) project (open-source) which has a similar purpose, and see what words / terms they use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `Identifier` is too generic for my use case.

Comment: And I think you misunderstood the meaning of `symbol` in that context. I'm not talking about characters or bytes but exported symbols from a binary.

Comment: And how is "functions ... and types ... from a C source file" similar with "exported symbols from a binary"? Now I understand better your meaning of "symbol", but the question is now suddenly ambiguous.